# how can we change the color of the picker view selection indicator?

Tags: iphone

HI all

i am using the uipicker view and i want to change the color of that picker by default it shows some bluish color but i need it in a gary color how can we do it

THanks

Balraj verma

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a custom view for the selection indicator to do this.  I have some code at home that does this, and I'll post it here when I get home from work.